# Textbook request for Linear Cellular Automata, if possible with an abstract algebraic approach

Tags: reference-request, cellular-automata

I am a final semester pure math undergrad, and I became interested in Linear Cellular Automatas.I became interested after reading Klaus Sutner's [article](https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/15859-s11/notes/sutner.pdf). In the article, a little abstract algebra is used, linear mappings, a vector space over $F_2$, I did use a bit of group theory to prove tiny things here and there.

**Question:** Can someone please recommend me their favorite introductory textbook on linear cellular automata? I do not know how it is usually approached, but if possible an abstract algebraic approach is much appreciated (also helps keep my algebra fresh)!

As to my background (so you can judge if a book would be too hard for me or not), I have taken a standard linear algebra class, 2 abstract algebra classes (groups, rings, fields), 2 classes of graph theory (pretty far, we covered Turan graphs, Ramsey theory, etc), and a standard theory of algorithm class (it was a common class with CS students).

Comment: I forgot, I've seen that there is McIntosh's book, but I haven't touched it much..

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We generally discourage "book recommendation" questions, as they tend to be subjective (see our [help/dont-ask]).  This is especially true when asking people for their favorite book.  The format for a book recommendation question that works better here is to list your requirements, do some research (I recommend that you look for university courses on the topic and see what textbook they use), and list what books you've considered so far and why you've rejected them (which requirements do they fail?).  If you just want opinions, that's better for Amazon book reviews.